# Eliminate void ** vs. any_struct_t ** warning

Tags: c, pointers

How do I correctly eliminate this warning while having the compiler check to make sure the argument passed is a **pointer to a pointer**?

```
void somefunc (void **elements)
{
    // This function works on any array type
    // Maybe it prints pointer addresses
    void **pp;
    for (pp = elements; *pp; pp ++)
        printf ("address: %x\n", *pp);
}

int main (const char *cmdline)
{
    typedef struct {
        int a, b, c;
    } any_struct_t;

    any_struct_t *group[25] = {0}; // (any_struct_t **) 
    group[0] = malloc (sizeof(any_struct_t));
    somefunc(group); // <--- WARNING (any_struct_t **) vs. (void **)
    getchar ();
    exit (0);
}
```

Is there a **"double void"** type of pointer or some super-obscure C trick that can be employed here to get rid of this warning correctly:

```
I want this warning to go away via code:
warning: passing argument 1 of 'somefunc' from incompatible pointer type 
expected 'void **' but argument is of type 'any_struct_t **'
```

The function wants a pointer to a pointer, it doesn't care what type of pointer it is.

I could eliminate the warning by casting to (void *) but then the compiler no longer would check to see if it is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: What's the reason why you have an array of pointers, where each pointer points to one single struct? Is there a reason why you can't have an array of structs instead?

Comment: The compiler is not really checking for a pointer to a pointer anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to make it do so?

Comment: @lundin -- in practice, but not in the example, I dynamically each member and there could be 10,000 of them.  Keeping them in a single struct array would not be friendly to realloc such a large piece of memory.  So I allocate them via pointers.

Comment: One (untested) idea is to wrap the function in a macro. The macro deferences the argument twice, throws away the result, then calls somefunc. For example, `#define somefunc_wrapper(x) do{ (void)**(x); somefunc((void**)(x)); } while (0)`

Comment: Haha, I've done that.  But I lose any kind of type checking.  I am hoping there is a an obscure trick.

Comment: I suppose I could have some #ifdef DEBUG stuff in the macro that tries to double de-reference like sizeof(**array) - sizeof(**array) to make sure it is at least a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `void**` and `struct anything**` are not compatible because `void*` doesn't have to have the same representation as other pointers. The standard allows e.g. `sizeof(void*)>sizeof(struct anything*)`.

Comment: How could malloc work if pointers don't have the same size?  malloc has the return type (void *)

Comment: `malloc` can and does work perfectly in such situation. What kind of problem do you expect to happen?

Comment: Are you using lots of different types or just one type?  If you're just using one type, why not just use that type instead of void.  Also the printf should be using %p for printing pointers.

Comment: The simple answer is `somefunc((void **)group);`

Comment: I'm using a great many different types.  The %x was an oversight quickly trying to type up an example.

Comment: Relevant passage from the standard: "A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type.48) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All
pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same
representation or alignment requirements."

Comment: That is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

`void*` is the only generic pointer type, which every other pointer type can get implicitly converted to/from. This does not apply to `void**` though, because formally a `void**` doesn't need to have the same implementation as a `x**`.

However, as you noted, you can simply cast to `void*` and the warning will go away. In theory, that wouldn't be portable. In practice, I very much doubt you'll ever get any problems from doing so.

So the only reason why you wouldn't just cast to `void*` and move on, is if you are pedantically concerned about type safety. In case you are, you should write a function to handle each separate pointer type.

For example, in C11, you can do this somewhat elegantly with the `_Generic` keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    int a, b, c;
} any_struct_t;


#define some_func(ptr) \
_Generic( (ptr), \
          any_struct_t**: some_any_struct)(ptr)

void some_any_struct (any_struct_t** pp)
{
  for(; *pp != NULL; pp++)
  {
    printf ("address: %p\n", (void*)*pp);
  }
}


int main(void)
{
  any_struct_t* array [4] = {0};

  array[0] = malloc(10*sizeof(any_struct_t));
  array[1] = malloc( 1*sizeof(any_struct_t));
  array[2] = malloc( 5*sizeof(any_struct_t));
  array[3] = NULL;

  some_func(array);

  void* void_array[3];
  some_func(void_array);  // will cause compiler error, because void** is not supported
}
```

Comment: I will have to investigate this _Generic keyword.  But yes, some sort of type safety is important because some functions I have take the array (any_type_t **) and some modify the array address itself 3x pointer (any_type_t ***).

Comment: @B.Nadolson Why would you ever want to modify the array address? There's a general rule of thumb saying that if you ever find yourself in need of three stars, you need to re-consider your program design. All of this does sound needlessly complex, you can probably simplify things a lot if you make a common ADT which encapsulates all the allocation, indirection and indexing.

Comment: Dynamic vector arrays with a block of pointers that provides for (rare) expansion.  A combination of a linked list, dynamic array, block allocs and a fixed-size list for fast indexing, fast sorting, provides static allocations and can be initiated with a single line like char **strings = string_vector_from_list ("apple", "orange", "banana", NULL);  vector_resize(strings, 25) /*upsize to 25*/;  Can add, move, sort, delete.  Not limited to any data type.  your_struct_t **something = vector_array_alloc (something, 25 /*num items*/);  Easy, quick, powerful, flexible.  But needed type checking.

Comment: @B.Nadolson Proper generic programming for such cases would be to implement a string class and a vector class with all the indirection and dirty details encapsulated. None of it should be exposed to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

This at least generates a compile-time error if the argument passed isn't (at least) a pointer-to-pointer.  It's not entirely idea, but at least has type checking.

```
void _somefunc (void **elements)
{
    // This function works on any array type
    // Maybe it prints pointer addresses
    void **pp;
    for (pp = elements; *pp; pp ++)
        printf ("address: %p\n", *pp);
}

// ENSURE AT LEAST A POINTER TO A POINTER IN DEBUG BUILDS, WILL CAUSE ERROR IF NOT.
// error: invalid type argument of unary '*'
#ifdef DEBUG
    // Ensure at least a pointer to a pointer.  Compile-time error if not.
    #define somefunc(x) _somefunc ((void **)x + sizeof(**x) - sizeof(**x)) 
#else
    #define somefunc(x) _somefunc (((void **)x) // No warnings in release
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void somefunc (void **elements)
{
// This function works on any array type
// Maybe it prints pointer addresses
any_struct_t **pp;
for (pp = (any_struct_t *)elements; *pp; pp ++)
    printf ("address: %x\n", *pp);
}

int main (const char *cmdline)
{
    typedef struct {
    int a, b, c;
} any_struct_t;

void *group[25] = {0}; // (any_struct_t **) 
group[0] = malloc (sizeof(any_struct_t));
somefunc(group); // <--- WARNING (any_struct_t **) vs. (void **)
getchar ();
exit (0);
```

}